# Platform.worker and basic usage of ports

Tags: elm

UPDATE: solved by myself (details underneath original question)

I am just getting started with Elm, and I am trying to make a worker to do some logic for me. I made a basic program to try to understand how `Platform.worker` and ports work. My goal is that whatever I type in the text box should update in `elm_output` instantaneously, and in `my_field` whenever I hit the "Submit" button.

It compiles, and it updates in `my_field` whenever I hit "Submit", however, the `elm_output` remains empty no matter what I type in the text box. What is my mistake?

Index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Main</title>
    <script src="src/elm.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="elm"></div>
    <input id="my_field"></input>
    <button id="my_field_submit">Submit</button>
    <p id="my_display"></p>
    <br><br>
    <p id="elm_output"></p>
</body>
<script src="view.js"></script>
</html>
```

view.js:

```js
var myField = document.getElementById("my_field");

var app = Elm.Main.init({
    node: document.getElementById("elm"),
    flags: myField.value
});

var myFieldSubmit = document.getElementById("my_field_submit");
myFieldSubmit.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("my_display").innerHTML = myField.value;
}

app.ports.textInput.send(document.getElementById("my_field").value);
app.ports.textOutput.subscribe(function(data) {
    document.getElementById("elm_output").innerHTML = data;
});
```

src/Main.elm:

```
port module Main exposing (..)

main = Platform.worker
    {
    init = init
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    }

type alias Model = { myTextVal : String }

init : String -> (Model, Cmd MyMsg)
init str = (Model str, Cmd.none)

type MyMsg = InMsg String

update : MyMsg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd MyMsg)
update msg model = case msg of
    InMsg str -> (Model str, textOutput str)

port textInput : (String -> msg) -> Sub msg
port textOutput : String -> Cmd msg

decodeValue : String -> MyMsg
decodeValue str = InMsg str

subscriptions : Model -> Sub MyMsg
subscriptions model = textInput decodeValue
```

Compiled with:
`elm make src/Main.elm --output src/elm.js`

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1: also, do I have to use flags in my init? I am always going to initialize `myTextVal` to `""` anyway.

Edit 2: SOLVED THIS QUESTION MYSELF.

I found the problem by adding `console.log` statements to the parts in my JS code which involved the Elm ports.

The problem was that Javascript does not constantly update Elm whenever a change is made. Instead, Javascript only sends information to Elm exactly once, whenever the `app.ports.xyzabc.send` function is called. In my old code, I only called this function once, when the document was loaded. Instead, I have to call it whenever the text input is changed in order to get the result I want.

New code:

(Index.html remained unchanged)

NEW view.js

```js
var myField = document.getElementById("my_field");

var app = Elm.Main.init({
    node: document.getElementById("elm"),
});

var myFieldSubmit = document.getElementById("my_field_submit");
myFieldSubmit.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("my_display").innerHTML = myField.value;
};

myField.oninput = function() {
    console.log("text changed");
    app.ports.textInput.send(myField.value);
};

app.ports.textOutput.subscribe(function(data) {
    console.log("received text output from Elm");
    document.getElementById("elm_output").innerHTML = data;
});
```

Console output:

```
received text output from Elm
text changed
```

(repeats whenever the text within myField changes)

Additionally, it is possible to initialize a `Platform.worker` without flags, and the solution is exactly what you think it would be:

NEW Main.elm

```
port module Main exposing (..)

main = Platform.worker
    {
    init = init
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    }

type alias Model = { myTextVal : String }

init : () -> (Model, Cmd MyMsg)
init _ = (Model "", Cmd.none)

type MyMsg = InMsg String

update : MyMsg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd MyMsg)
update msg model = case msg of
    InMsg str -> (Model str, textOutput str)

port textInput : (String -> msg) -> Sub msg
port textOutput : String -> Cmd msg

decodeValue : String -> MyMsg
decodeValue str = InMsg str

subscriptions : Model -> Sub MyMsg
subscriptions model = textInput decodeValue
```

This was actually my first Elm program, and I'm happy that it worked perfectly! As always, JavaScript was the problem, not Elm.

Comment: Congrats on getting it working. Always tough to get the hello world program out of the way. Why not make a blog post out of it?

Comment: And an answer here instead of answering it in the question. You are allowed, even encouraged, to answer your own questions.